# Direction cosine and direct product of two Lebesgue measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let G be a bounded finitely connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with 2-smooth boundary $\partial G$ each connected component of which has positive Gaussian curvature.

> I guess the open 2-ball fulfills this property.

Each sufficiently small open subset of $\partial G$ can be represented as the graph $\Gamma$ of a 2-smooth function $\phi(\tau)$ for $\tau \in V$, where V is an open subset of the hyperplane perpendicular to one of the basis vectors e of the space $\mathbb{R}^m$.

> Lets take for example the upper half-circle. The upper half-circle can be represented by the 2-smooth function $f(x): (-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \sqrt{1-x^2}$. $V=(-1,1)$ is an open subset of the hyperplane perpendicular to the basis vector (0,1) of the space $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $t(\sigma)$ be the cosine of the angle between e and $n(\sigma)$, where $n(\sigma)$ is the outer unit normal vector to the boundary $\partial G$ at $\sigma \in \partial G$.

> The outer unit normal is $(cos(t),sin(t)), t\in [0,\pi]$. Hence $t(\sigma)=sin(t)$, $t\in [0,\pi]$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine

Let $\Pi \subset V$ be an open $(m-1)$-dimensional parallelepiped with edges parallel to the basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

> Let $\Pi=(-1,1)$.

$\Gamma(\Pi)$ is the graph of the function $\phi(\tau)$ for $\tau \in \Pi$ and $\xi$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\Pi$ for dimension $m-1$.

> The graph $\Gamma(\Pi)$ is the upper half-circle and $\xi(\Pi)=2$.

$\eta = \max_{\sigma \in \Gamma(\Pi)} t(\sigma)$, and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^1$, $0<a<b<\eta^{-1}$.

> $\eta=1$. So let's say b=0.8 and a=0.3.

We introduce the set $F\subset [0,1)\times\partial G$ in the following way:

$$
F= \big\{ (u,\sigma) : \sigma \in \Gamma(\Pi), at(\sigma)<u<bt(\sigma)\big\}
$$

> Every point $\sigma \in \partial G$ from the boundary $\partial G$ gets assigned an interval based on $t(\sigma)$. Since $t(\sigma)$ is between 0 and 1 this shrinks the interval (a,b).

Let $\mu$ equal to the direct product of the Lebesgue measures on $[0,1)$ and $\partial G$.

> How do I write down the integral over the direct product of a surface and an interval?

The research paper I am currently reading claims (unfortunately without proof...) that $\mu(F)=\xi(b-a)$.

> So in my example $\mu(F)=2*(0.8-0.3)=1$.